# Debugging Error: Unfortunately app has stopped working

Tags: android-studio

I keep getting error when I try to run my code on Android studio emulator. I have tried fixing anything I can but I am new to coding and software. I have created a splash screen.
Below is my Java code.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val SPLASH_TIME_OUT=3000;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Handler().postDelayed(object:Runnable{
        public override fun run(){
            val home= Intent (this@MainActivity,EntryScreenActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(home)
            finish()
        }

    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT.toLong())



    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
}
```

And this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sararafiq94.com.carparkingreservationsystem.MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appname"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/applogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appname"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_marginBottom="217dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/appname" />
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: When i run it on emulator, it says that Unfortunately, my app has stopped working.
You want me to copy paste Logcat?